# Warning message Foundation 6

Tags: zurb-foundation, warnings, message

I would like to put a warning message using Foundation6.

If it's possible, something like Bootstrap Message :
[image]

In the Foundation Docs, we have this : http://foundation.zurb.com/sites/docs/v/5.5.3/components/alert_boxes.html .

But it's not working with me, it's like I missed an import (classes doesn't work).

Any idea ?

**EDIT**

My code is simple :

```
<!doctype html>
<html class="no-js" lang="en">
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta http-equiv="x-ua-compatible" content="ie=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Foundation for Sites</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/my-css.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/app.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/icons/foundation-icons.css">
  </head>
  <body ng-app="app">
      <div class="row">
          <div class="columns">
              <div class="text-center">
                  <div data-alert class="alert-box warning round">
                      This is a warning alert that is rounded.
                      <a href="#" class="close">&times;</a>
                  </div>
```

app.css is Foundation stylesheet minified.

Comment: Do you have any code?

Comment: I edited my post

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you looked at the Foundation 6 docs? Warning messages are called callouts in Foundation 6 and you add the class `callout` to the div, together with another class depending on the kind of alert you are going for. For a warning, you'd use:

```
<div class="callout warning">
  <h5>This is a warning callout</h5>
</div>
```

Check out the [docs](http://foundation.zurb.com/sites/docs/callout.html#).

Comment: Yeah I've looked at the doc, but not at the right place .. Thank you !